# Jquery scroll to top of each section with button press not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to animate the scroll to each section on button press. I have done lots of research and came across with this:

```
$('ul.nav').find('a').click(function () {
    var $href = $(this).attr('href');
     var $anchor = $('#' + $href).offset();
     $('body').animate({scrollTop: $anchor.top});
     return false;
 });
```

But it's not working. It just scroll without the animation. Can somebody help me please?

My HTML code:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="index.php">Hlavní stránka</a></li>
        <li><a href="#rooms">Naše pokoje</a></li>
        <li><a href="#prizes">Ceník</a></li>
        <li><a href="#footer">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just used a wrong selector...

Try with this:

```
$('#nav ul li a').click(function(e) {

    // Get the href
    var $href = $(this).attr('href');

    // Animate only if the href contains the # character.
    if($href.substr(0,1) == "#"){}
      e.preventDefault();

      // Here, the # sign is already present.
      var $anchor = $($href).offset();
      $('body').animate({scrollTop: $anchor.top},1000);  // Set a delay here, in milliseconds.
    }
});
```

And I would use [`preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) instead of `return false;`

**EDITED** to care about the first anchor which looks like to be a "real" link to trigger a page load.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
$('#nav ul li a').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```